# Specify a t2 instance VPC using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

t2 instances only work with a VPC (as documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html#t2-instances-vpc-support).  So when running via AWS CLI, how do I specify a VPC on the command line?  I've followed the document here (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-set-up-new-instance.html) and have the command line setup as outlined:

```
aws ec2 run-instances \
  --image-id amiID \
  --key-name keyName \
  --user-data file://instance-setup.sh \
  --count 1 \
  --instance-type instanceType \
  --iam-instance-profile Name=CodeDeployDemo-EC2-Instance-Profile
```

I realize using an m3 instance works as expected, but I'd like a t2.micro since this instance will only be used for deployment.

Comment: You need to set the `--subnet-id` of the command. Full docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command will automatically use the **Default** VPC and a random subnet (which also selects the Availability Zone). If you wish to specify the VPC & Subnet, use `--subnet-id` parameter.

To select a T2 instance, be sure to include an instance type identifier, such as `--instance-type t2.micro`

Also, T2 instances require an AMI configured for [HVM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/virtualization_types.html) (Windows uses this by default, but Linux has a choice of PV or HVM).